# How to get the count of values in table using linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

im required to make a query to db to fetch data fro a highchart widget in our site here is the code I use currently,

```cs
var highChartsData = 
    (from a in db.roomdetails
    join b in db.ApplySchedule on a.RoomId equals b.RoomID
    where b.Status == true
    select new HighlinePie
    {
        Title = a.RoomName,
        Date = b.MDate,
        Value = db.ApplySchedule.Where(x => x.RoomID == a.RoomId).GroupBy(x=>x.MDate).Count(),
}).ToList();
```

The problem with this approach is right now get the total count but what i need is the count based on date, for example if there was two entry on date 12/09/20201 and three entry on 14/09/20201 the data should be "Title,12/09/20201,2","Title,14/09/20201,3".

Comment: Sounds like you need group by? Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results Was that what you were after?

Comment: you need to apply `group by` on this date field and then use `Count` on each returned group of your interest

Comment: yes like what you shared but im confused, how do I send the data to a model,should I use a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use grouping:

```cs
var groupQuery = 
    from a in db.roomdetails
    join b in db.ApplySchedule on a.RoomId equals b.RoomID
    where b.Status == true
    group b by new { a.RoomName, b.MDate } into g
    select new HighlinePie
    {
        Title = g.Key.RoomName,
        Date = g.Key.MDate,
        Value = g.Count()
    };

var highChartsData = groupQuery.ToList();
```